# create simple select with basic inner join using function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm new to postgresql and i got basic knowledge of join statements now i'm trying to create a function out of this

```
select r.studid,r.subjcode,r.section,s.subjdesc,r.sy,r.sem,r.grade,r.gcompl
from registration r
inner join subject s ON r.subjcode = s.subjcode
where studid = '2020-2001' AND r.grade = 'INC' AND COALESCE(gcompl, '') = ''
ORDER BY studid DESC;
```

I'm currently using postgresql v9.5 w/ pgadmin III
edit i got it working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION srgb.viewincgrade(p_studid char)
RETURNS TABLE (studid char,subjcode char,section char ,subjdesc 
varchar,sy char,sem char,grade varchar,gcompl varchar)
AS
$$
BEGIN
return query
select 
r.studid,r.subjcode,r.section,s.subjdesc,r.sy,r.sem,r.grade,r.gcompl
from registration r
INNER JOIN subject s ON r.subjcode = s.subjcode
where r.studid = p_studid AND r.grade = 'INC' AND COALESCE(r.gcompl, 
'') = ''
ORDER BY studid DESC;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: well im trying to create a function that select with a join function

Comment: i can create one but with no join statement sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you show us how are you creating your function?

Comment: i got it working thanks for trying help